# Designing Inputs with Placeholders

Tags: html, css

I'm about to kill myself, because I can't make this input full width. Anyway here is my code:

```
.outer{
  background: #111;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin 20px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
input{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And this is my html code:

```
<div class="outer"><form action="" method="post">
  <input name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
</form></div>
```

I'm having a problem with these codes. I wrote width: 100%, but input is longer than 600px. I will use this in a responsive template. So I have to do this right. But I can't do it! If I remove padding, then it looks normal. But I need padding code in here. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `box-sizing` to your input styling and remove the width from `.outer`, it will be 100%.

**CSS:**

```
.outer{
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
  margin 0px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

input{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing : border-box;‌​
  -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
  box-sizing : border-box;
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jvgd1xh/).